# In Android Studio, all com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version

Tags: android, gradle

I recently upgraded to Android Studio 2.3. and this error started appearing:

[image]

Here is my list of libraries:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile files('libs/wekaSTRIPPED.jar')
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.8.1@aar') { // Material Drawer
    transitive = true
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
compile 'com.github.wendykierp:JTransforms:3.1'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.3.0'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.borax12.materialdaterangepicker:library:1.9'
compile 'com.evernote:android-job:1.1.7' // Scheduling library
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the problem like you when updating to Android Studio 2.3. I solved by I searched in my project all support library using `25.1.1` (I searched **25.1.1**) and replace with 25.2.0. I think many code using 25.1.1, in your library and your project.

You can open external lib in your project to show all dependency. You should update to new library version(lib using support library):

For ex:
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer - new version is `5.8.2` using 25.2.0

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, as you can see in the library list I am using the latest version - 25.2.0. Or I am mistaken?

Comment: You should search in your project and library .I use notepadd++ for searching because it can found **25.1.1** in the compile file.

Comment: Not sure how to do the search. Are you doing this File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies?

Comment: Yes, if you see only 25.2.0, it 's ok, if you see another version of support lib. You need to change all support lib to 25.2.0, including in your libraries using support lib.